# Having a struggle in a number-guessing game in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I created a number guessing game, that is the code:

```
#Guess the number game

import random

guesses = 6
number = random.randint(0, 100)
win = False

while guesses > 0:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))

    guesses -= 1

    if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high", guesses, "remaining")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low", guesses, "remaining")
    elif guess - number < 6:
        print("You are very close")
    else:
        print("Congrats, you guessed")
        win = True
        guesses = 0

if win == False:
    print("Sorry, you didn't guess the number", number)
```

However, I want it so that if the user inputs a number which is bigger by 5 or lower by 5 than the random number(number variable), to print "You are close".

Comment: `elif guess - 5 <= number <= guess + 5:` This needs to be placed before your other checks as if/elif statements are checked in order. You should also break out of the while loop when the guess is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
import random    
guesses = 6
number = random.randint(0, 100)
win = False

while guesses > 0:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))

    guesses -= 1

    if guess == number:
        win = True
        guesses = 0
    elif abs(guess - number) < 6: 
        print("You are very close")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high", guesses, "remaining")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low", guesses, "remaining")

if win == False:
    print("Sorry, you didn't guess the number", number)
else:
    print("Congrats, you guessed correct")
```

you need to check early if the number is close (before the `guess > number` checks); and [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#abs) is there to accept a difference in both directions

your `guess - number < 6` will never be reached; one of the 2 conditions above will already have been met; and without the `abs` this condition will be true even for very small guesses.

and maybe it would be better to loop over the guesses with a `for` loop and `break` if the solution has been found.